# Setting MS C# compiler options via environmental variables?

Tags: c#, csc

Is there any way to set default options passed to csc.exe? In particular, I'm interested in supressing copyright messages. For example, for cl.exe and ml.exe I have

```
CL = /nologo
ML = /nologo
```

Comment: I don't believe that functionality is baked into csc.exe, but you could create a batch file that interprets the environment variables and uses them to invoke the real csc.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite csc.rsp

Added

/nologo

csc.rsp location is same folder of csc.exe

E.g.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319